# MySQL how to return value from mutiplitcaton in Column values

Tags: mysql

data in one table KPI prepared

Comment: I'll have to admit that I have not even the faintest idea of what you're talking about. Try and [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score -1):

you can do folow step befor:

1. Group_Concat to string
2. Subtring, convert to value int,float with multilication
3. Final return
   exp:

> 

```
 DECLARE multil FLOAT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE strlist NVARCHAR(500);
SET strlist =
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(LENGTH(coefficient) SEPARATOR ',')
   FROM kpi
   LIMIT 1);
WHILE INSTR(strlist, ",") > 0 DO
SET multil = multil * CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(strlist, ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED);
SET strlist = MID(strlist, INSTR(strlist, ',') + 1);
END WHILE;
SET multil = multil * CAST(strlist AS UNSIGNED);
SELECT multil;
```

> 